# Vue2 timepicker : default values from API

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, mongoose, timepicker

I am building a simple app with vue2 timepicker. I know how to set the default values for the start time and end time in vue js.

```html
 <li v-for="day in myDayArray" v-bind:key=day>
    <div>
    <label> {{day.Day }} : </label>
    <vue-timepicker class="timepicker" v-model="day.starttime" format="HH:mm" placeholder="Start Time" :minute-interval="30"></vue-timepicker>
     <span> To </span>
    <vue-timepicker class="timepicker" v-model="day.endtime" format="HH:mm" placeholder="End Time" :minute-interval="30"></vue-timepicker>  
    </div>
 </li>
```

The default values are here -

```js
data: function() {
    return {
      myDayArray: [
        {
          Day: "Monday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Tuesday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Wednesday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Thursday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Friday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Saturday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        },
        {
          Day: "Sunday",
          starttime: {
            HH: '15',
            mm: '30'
          },
          endtime: {
            HH: '21',
            mm: '00'
          }
        }]
```

If the user changes the start time and end time, I save it in the database for the user. The next time, how do I display those values in the start time and end time instead of the default values set initially? In other words, how do I set the default values in vue2 timepicker from the backend database?

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: add one computed property then uses backend data to overwrite the elements of `this.myDayArray`. finally `v-for` that computed property.

Comment: In your component's `created` hook, fetch the saved values and overwite `myDayArray`. What have you tried?